# Weblogic DB2 DataSource: what determines the transaction isolation level?

Tags: transactions, db2, weblogic-10.x, isolation-level

An application accesses a mainframe DB2 via direct JDBC, using a DataSource provided by a Weblogic application server 10.0.

1. How do I configure the transaction isolation level in Weblogic for a DataSource, if that is even possible?
2. If the application does not set the transaction isolation level on the connection itself (which sets it to the default, which is "read committed", I think), but uses a SQL statement suffix "with UR", will the statements be executed with "uncommitted read"?
3. What is the easiest way to find out what locks an application aquires in the DB2? It is a mainframe DB2 instance that is used of a whole plethora of applications...

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass the isolation level as a parameter to the data source. The exact name varyies between DB2 Linux/Unix/Windows and z/OS (in z/OS it is currentIsolationLevel). To find out, open the data source class in Eclipse and look for an approriate setter. Note that in some data sources, the isolation level must be specified by a numeric value between 0 and 4, see class com.ibm.websphere.models.config.appresources.WASIsolationLevelType.class for a definition.
2. SQL statement suffix "WITH UR" is respected and takes precedence over the data source config.
3. This quite a different topic unrelated to Java and Weblogic.